# My side-nav collape will not work inside <form>

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I've been trying to fix this for a while now, when my side-bar is inside a  tag it stops working.

HTML:

```
<nav class="aptest-sidenav aptest-collapse aptest-white aptest-animate-left" style="z-index:3;width:300px;" id="mySidenav">
            <br />
            <div class="aptest-container aptest-row">
                <div class="aptest-col s4">
                    <img src="/aptestimages/avatar2.png" class="aptest-circle aptest-margin-right" style="width:46px" />
                </div>
                <div class="aptest-col s8">
                    <span>Welcome, <strong><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Name_txt" Text="" /></strong></span><br />                     
        </nav>
            <div class="aptest-overlay aptest-hide-large aptest-animate-opacity" onclick="aptest_close()" style="cursor:pointer" title="close side menu" id="myOverlay"></div>
        <!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
        <div class="aptest-main" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:43px;">
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:992px){.aptest-sidenav.aptest-collapse{display:none}.aptest-main{margin-left:0!important;margin-right:0!important}}
@media screen and (min-width:993px){.aptest-sidenav.aptest-collapse{display:block!important}}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var mySidenav = $("#mySidenav");
                var overlayBg = $("#myOverlay");
                $("#aptest_open").click(function () {

                    if (mySidenav.style.display === 'block') {
                        mySidenav.style.display = 'none';
                        overlayBg.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        alert("2");
                        mySidenav.style.display = 'block';
                        overlayBg.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
                function aptest_close() {
                    alert();
                    mySidenav.style.display = "none";
                    overlayBg.style.display = "none";
                }
            });

        </script>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, ive tried using jQuery, pure JS I cant get it to work. The JS above doesn't even run. I'm really confused. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What you mean: *The JS above doesn't even run* ?

Comment: Farzin, I have added 'alert();' into the JS but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not have any element with `id="aptest_open"`. Your alert code is in a code block that works only by click on element with id aptest_open.
2. When you select an element by jquery selector, To change it's styles you need to yous **css** not style. In code snippet I added a button with id aptest_open and edited the problem.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<nav class="aptest-sidenav aptest-collapse aptest-white aptest-animate-left" style="z-index:3;width:300px;" id="mySidenav">This is my side nav
            <br />
            <div class="aptest-container aptest-row">
                <div class="aptest-col s4">
                    <img src="/aptestimages/avatar2.png" class="aptest-circle aptest-margin-right" style="width:46px" />
                </div>
                <div class="aptest-col s8">
                    <span>Welcome, <strong><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Name_txt" Text="" /></strong></span><br />                     
        </nav>
            <div class="aptest-overlay aptest-hide-large aptest-animate-opacity" onclick="aptest_close()" style="cursor:pointer" title="close side menu" id="myOverlay"></div>
        <!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
        <div class="aptest-main" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:43px;">
        </div>
        
        <input type="button" id="aptest_open" value="aptest_open" />



<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var mySidenav = $("#mySidenav");
                var overlayBg = $("#myOverlay");
                $("#aptest_open").click(function () {
                    if (mySidenav.css('display') === 'block') {
                        mySidenav.css('display', 'none');
                        
                    } else {
                        alert("2");
                        mySidenav.css('display', 'block');                        
                    }
                });
                function aptest_close() {
                    alert();
                    mySidenav.style.display = "none";
                    overlayBg.style.display = "none";
                }
            });

        </script>
```